# How to get attributes in Json String in servlet

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax

How can I get each attribute within a Json String?

I got the Json by converting first my array of objects in JavaScript via JSON.stringify. Afterwards I used ajax to pass the string to my servlet.

Servlet Code:

```
String data = request.getParameter("jsonData");       
System.out.println("json data: " + data);
```

Result:

```
[{"courseID":"1","codePI":"PO-BSINSYS-02.01","curriculumID":"3"},
{"courseID":"2","codePI":"PO-BSINSYS-02.02","curriculumID":"3"}]
```

What I want is to get the individual values of the json so that I can assign them later to my object.

E.g.

```
ArrayList<Curriculum> arrCur = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int x = 0; x < array.size(); x++) {
        Curriculum cur = new Curriculum();
        cur.setCourseID(courseID[x]);
        cur.setCodePO(codePI[x]);
        cur.setCurriculumID(curriculumID[x]);
        arrCur.add(cur);
    }
```

Comment: Parse the JSON, use the parsed result.

Answer (score 0):

As "crowder" mentioned, you need to parse the json.
There are several ways to do it.

1. low-level libraries that would convert your string into a
   JSONObject which is sort of a map (with keys "courseID", "codePO"
   etc). At the time I used fasterxml but I see a newer approach here:
   http://crunchify.com/java-how-to-parse-jsonobject-and-jsonarrays/
2. Higher-level libraries that would map the json directly into
       Java business Objects such as "Curriculum". My own experience was
       focused on replacing the simple Servlet with Spring - see for
       example https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way if you are sending arry of object from javascript and if you class -

```
  class Curriculum{
        Integer courseID;
        String codePI;
        Integer curriculumID;
    }
```

Use like this -

```
String data = request.getParameter("jsonData"); 
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
java.lang.reflect.Type curriculumType =new com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken<List<Curriculum>>(){}.getType();

List<Curriculum> curriculum = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), curriculumType);
```

This will assign list of Curriculum. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jackson-databind API to convert your json to java object.

Create your bean for Curriculum.

```
class Curriculum{
Integer courseID;
String codePI;
Integer curriculumID;
public Integer getCourseID() {
    return courseID;
}
public void setCourseID(Integer courseID) {
    this.courseID = courseID;
}
public String getCodePI() {
    return codePI;
}
public void setCodePI(String codePI) {
    this.codePI = codePI;
}
public Integer getCurriculumID() {
    return curriculumID;
}
public void setCurriculumID(Integer curriculumID) {
    this.curriculumID = curriculumID;
}
}
```

Following is the code to convert your json to Curriculum object

```
JSONArray jsonArray = getJSONArray();

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    for(int i =0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        //convert json string to object
        try {
            Curriculum curr= objectMapper.readValue(jsonData.toString().getBytes(), Curriculum.class);
            System.out.println(curr);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```